# Populate a column with part of the unique directory of each file?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I want to add a column and populate it with the part of each files unique address in the directory:

Example:
say I have two files from each subfolder named: `45554` and `32456`
Therefore their paths are like:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INB\INB.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INB\INB.shp
```

so I need to extract each rows `-3` position and populate the new column.

Like:

```
   new_col
     45554
     45554
     32456
     32456
     etc..
```

The code:

```
folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE")
    shapefiles = []
        for shpfile in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
            try:
                shapefiles.append(geopandas.read_file(shpfile))
                shpfile['col'] = shpfile.split("\\")[-3]
            except FionaValueError as ex:
                if not os.listdir(shpfile):
                    #print(f'{shpfile} is empty')
        gdf = pd.concat(shapefiles, sort=True).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
        gdf.to_file(folder / 'compiled.shp')
```

This gives:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-bc0ddf8da6d3> in <module>()
      5             #shpfile['col'] = shpfile.split("\\")[-3]
      6             shapefiles.append(geopandas.read_file(shpfile))
----> 7             shpfile['col'] = shpfile.split("\\")[-3]
      8         except FionaValueError as ex:
      9             if not os.listdir(shpfile):

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

In the end the concatenated files will have their columns with also an extra column that will contain the numbers from their directories as said earlier.

Comment: `shpfile` is the string representation of the path to your file. It is not the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try and replacing `\\` with `/` before you split the path for the numbered parent folder.

```
folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE")
shapefiles = []
    for shpfile in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
        try:
            shapefiles.append(geopandas.read_file(shpfile))
            shpfile['col'] = shpfile.replace('\\','/').split("/")[-3]
        except FionaValueError as ex:
            if not os.listdir(shpfile):
                #print(f'{shpfile} is empty')
    gdf = pd.concat(shapefiles, sort=True).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
    gdf.to_file(folder / 'compiled.shp')
```